# how do i change my main player in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

im new about scripting and i want to make a little free shop, my game is about a running car that have to avoid objects, so in the shop i want to that when the user press select http://prntscr.com/270ws5 the main car that is this one http://prntscr.com/270y45 , become the car that they selected, thanks

```
//These variables will note which keys are down
//We don't need the up or down key just yet
//but we will later
var leftKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var upKeyPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var downKeyDown:Boolean = false;
//the main character's speed
var mainSpeed:Number = 7;
//whether or not the main guy is jumping
var mainJumping:Boolean = false;
//how quickly should the jump start off
var jumpSpeedLimit:int = 20;
//the current speed of the jump;
var jumpSpeed:Number = 0;

//adding a listener to mcMain which will make it move 
//based on the key strokes that are down
player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveChar);
function moveChar(event:Event):void{
    //if certain keys are down then move the character
    if(leftKeyDown){
        player.x -= mainSpeed;
    }
    if(rightKeyDown){
        player.x += mainSpeed;
    }
    if(upPressed || mainJumping){
        mainJump();
     gotoAndStop(2)
      gotoAndStop(3)
       gotoAndStop(4)
        gotoAndStop(5)


    }
}

//listening for the keystrokes
//this listener will listen for down keystrokes
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeysDown);
function checkKeysDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    //making the booleans true based on the keycode
    //WASD Keys or arrow keys
    if(event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 65){
        leftKeyDown = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 87){
        upPressed = true;
        gotoAndStop(2)
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68){
        rightKeyDown = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 83){
        downKeyDown = true;
    }
}
//this listener will listen for keys being released
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeysUp);
function checkKeysUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    //making the booleans false based on the keycode
    if(event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 65){
        leftKeyDown = false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 87){
        upPressed = false;
         gotoAndStop(2)
      gotoAndStop(3)
       gotoAndStop(4)
        gotoAndStop(5)

    }
    if(event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68){
        rightKeyDown = false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 83){
        downKeyDown = false;
    }
}

//jumping function
function mainJump():void{
    //if main isn't already jumping
    if(!mainJumping){
        //then start jumping
        mainJumping = true;
        jumpSpeed = jumpSpeedLimit*-1;
        player.y += jumpSpeed;
    } else {
        //then continue jumping if already in the air
        //crazy math that I won't explain
        if(jumpSpeed < 0){
            jumpSpeed *= 1 - jumpSpeedLimit/75;
            if(jumpSpeed > -jumpSpeedLimit/5){
                jumpSpeed *= -1;
            }
        }
        if(jumpSpeed > 0 && jumpSpeed <= jumpSpeedLimit){
            jumpSpeed *= 1 + jumpSpeedLimit/50;
        }
        player.y += jumpSpeed;
        //if main hits the floor, then stop jumping
        //of course, we'll change this once we create the level
        if(player.y >= stage.stageHeight - player.height){
            mainJumping = false;
            player.y = stage.stageHeight - player.height;
        }
    }
}
```

that is my car script, thanks a lot if someone can help me, to improve my script knowledge

Answer (score 0):

You give a property to `player`'s class of type `MovieClip` as it's movie clips you seem to have in your game to represent cars, which is then assigned an instance of a selected car. Then, whenever you want your `player` to `gotoAndStop()`, you address that to attached instance instead. Thus the instance will represent changeable graphics and the wrapper object (`player`) takes care of handling, collisions and other non-graphical stuff.

```
class Player extends Sprite {
    private var _car:MovieClip; // the instance
    public function Player() {
        _car=new MovieClip();
        addChild(_car);
    }
    public function get car():MovieClip { return _car; } // getter function
    public function set car(value:MovieClip):void {
        // setter function. We need to clean up our player from old car
        if (!value) return; // null car - no wai
        if (_car) removeChild(_car);
        _car=value;
        _car.x=0;
        _car.y=0; // place car at zero relative to player
        // this way you move the player, not the car, 
        // but MC playing is the car, not the player
        addChild(_car);
   }
   ...
}
```

Note that you can also relocate jump processing into Player class, so that you can just call `player.jump()` and don't care about the actual values, the player will then have to store the jumping constants, speeds, state (in midair or touching ground), etc etc.

Comment: Vesper do i can contact you?